# how to do i18n while using react-templates

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-templates

[react-templates](https://github.com/wix/react-templates) is a good solution to separate template and logic code,however,if i have multiply templates but referrer to one logic code,like i18n requests.
eg.

```
post.js //which is the logic code
post.en.rt //which is the template for english
post.es.rt //for spanish
```

how to load in post.js?

PS: i don't wanna load all language templates in post.js,that would be a big file and it would be a waste for network

Answer (score 0):

finaly,i use bundle loader with regexp to solove my question.

code like this

```
{ 
    test: /(en|cn)\.rt$/, 
    loaders: [
            "bundle?regExp=(en|cn)\.rt$&name=[1]",
            "react-templates-loader"
        ]
},
```

then all xxx.en.rt files will bundle into one en.js